# Can no longer connect to move_base server

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Apologies for this rather vague question, but has something changed with **move_base** over the past month in the ROS Electric debian version?  I have a simple Python script that worked perfectly a month ago and now it hangs on **move_base.wait_for_server()**.  I am running the move_base server and client script on the same machine and I have tried it on two different machines (both running Ubuntu 10.04) with the same problem. My script can be found at: http://code.google.com/p/pi-robot-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/experimental/pi_robot/pi_navigation/nodes/nav_test.py.

When running 'rostopic list /move_base' in the terminal where I am running my client script, I see the following nodes:

```
/move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/inflated_obstacles
/move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/obstacles
/move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/robot_footprint
/move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/unknown_space
/move_base/NavfnROS/plan
/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/cost_cloud
/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/global_plan
/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/local_plan
/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/parameter_updates
/move_base/current_goal
/move_base/global_costmap/inflated_obstacles
/move_base/global_costmap/obstacles
/move_base/global_costmap/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/global_costmap/parameter_updates
/move_base/global_costmap/robot_footprint
/move_base/global_costmap/unknown_space
/move_base/goal
/move_base/local_costmap/inflated_obstacles
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacles
/move_base/local_costmap/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/local_costmap/parameter_updates
/move_base/local_costmap/robot_footprint
/move_base/local_costmap/unknown_space
```

Any thoughts how I can debug this?

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27931/can-no-longer-connect-to-move_base-server/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2012-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-02-19**:
This doesn't really help, but: I am using the same service on lucid and it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, I found the problem.  For some reason, I had earlier set the update_frequency parameter to 0.0 in my global_costmap_params.yaml file.  Apparently this causes the move_base server to not accept client connections.  Once I set the update_frequence parameter to 1.0, everything started working again.

P.S. The reason I had set it to 0.0 was that I was trying to block off a room on my map by simply drawing a line across the doorway.  However, the robot kept clearing the line when the laser scan passed through that doorway.  Someone had suggested turning off the updates on the global costmap so I set the update frequency to 0.  Perhaps I only need to set the publish_frequency to 0 to get the desired behavior?

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2012-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1